# how to change button's text position when pressed?

Tags: android

I have used two pictures (nine-patch) for the background of buttons.
when `state_pressed="true"` the background changes. (I used selector)

I designed backgrounds somehow they look like the real buttons and when you press them, they go inside.

look at them when running my application on `AVD` (or any device)

[image: button not pressed]

[image: button pressed]

button's text is at the previous position.
what's the solution?

Comment: Maybe try adding some padding left and top for text button

Comment: why dont you draw 5 on the image

Comment: well padding should work @Chol is right

Comment: @AdeelTurk Because if I run my application in other devices with bigger screen the quality of picture comes down!

Comment: can you share the drawable you have created as selector

Comment: http://uploads.im/3X6vo.png
http://uploads.im/Lv10t.png

Comment: @Chol padding dose not work!

Comment: You can try to add the number as a textview in top of the button, and set translation to this textview when clicking

Comment: @Aditi I have added them in upper comment.

Comment: @user6657714 if its about picture quality then you can use .svg image. i was going through some lectures by google android developers program named udacity . they told about svg image and i used them they are great because they do not contain bitmaps they are actually some equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use svg image as backgroud which will never pixelate in any case 
for example creae a drawable and past given xml source in  it which will create a avg image now use it as drawable backgroung

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportWidth="50"
    android:viewportHeight="50">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#C03A2B"
        android:pathData="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ED7161"
        android:pathData="M6,18.078c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1c0-5.514,4.486-10,10-10c0.553,0,1,0.447,1,1s-0.447,1-1,1
c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8C7,17.631,6.553,18.078,6,18.078z" />
</vector>
```